# How can the performance of a neural network vary considerably without changing any parameters?

Tags: matlab, neural-network

I am training a neural network with 1 sigmoid hidden layer and a linear output layer. The network simply approximates a cosine function. The weights are initiliazed according to Nguyen-Widrow initialization and the biases are initialized to 1. I am using MATLAB as a platform.

Running the network a number of times without changing any parameters, I am getting results (mean squared error) which range from 0.5 to 0.5*10^-6. I cannot understand how the results can even vary that much, I'd imagine there would at least be a narrower and more consistent window of errors.

What could be causing such a big variance?

Comment: You might like to try datascience.stackexchange.com for the theory, but in short neural networks are fiddly to train. You should give a little code, including training params (and any features switched on/off) you use. There are probably a few things you could do to improve consistency of training results, but it is hard to tell from your description so far what is causing the massive variance. An mse of 0.5 implies the network has failed to learn at all.

Comment: It can be: not enough data to train properly, not enough complex NN, ... To make sure your results are consistent remember to manually set the training/testing data.

Comment: When the NN works correctly and the training data is big enough but the MSE is too high, it usually means that you need more neurons on your hidden layer OR that you need to add another hidden layer.